# What fourcc should I use when encoding mp4 videos with VP9?

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, mp4, vp9

My goal is to write an mp4 video using the `cv2` Python library, which itself depends on `ffmpeg`. What code should I use as the `fourcc` parameter, i.e.,:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'????')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code `vp09` (case-sensitive):

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'vp09')
```